# tcpdump not showing HTTP requests

Tags: http, tcpdump

I'm trying to use tcpdump to identify which IP address a particular person is coming from but I'm not seeing the HTTP commands as various web site show.  I've used the following to set up tcpdump:

```
nohup tcpdump -i eth0 -P in -nn -n -tttt -w /home/tcpdump/port80.log -C 100 -W 50 "port 80" > /home/tcpdump/nohup.log 2>&1 &
```

And I'm peridoically checking the file using

```
tcpdump -r port80.log00 -n -nn -A
```

I'm connecting to the following URL from a web browser:

```
http://10.10.0.50?test
```

And I was expecting to see a bunch of HTTP "GET" commands but tcpdump doesn't seem to be showing me the incoming messages.  Instead I just get something like

```
16:21:35.708250 IP 10.10.0.222.55924 > 10.10.0.50.80: Flags [S], seq 1869638484, win 8192, options [mss 1340,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
E..0@H@....\

..

.2.t.PopkT....p. ........<....
```

Looking at other info on using tcpdump for HTTP logging I'm should be seeing the "GET" command after the first few bytes of garbage.  There's no actual web server running - I'm only interested in seeing the incoming request as a test, hence the "?test" on the end to help me search the logs for the right thing.  I don't see that that's the issue tho'.

Any help very gratefully received.

Comment: Do you understand how TCP works? The `GET` or other HTTP-protocol entities won't be sent until the TCP three-way handshake has completed. Specifically, nothing HTTP-related will ever be sent in the initial SYN packet...

Comment: Obviously to the level of detail needed here I didn't understand how TCP works - hence my asking the question.  Now I do, thank you.